# How can I make my unnatural scrolling setting persistent between sessions?

Tags: 20.04, touchpad, scrolling, mouse-scroll, lxqt

My unnatural scrolling setting is not persistent between sessions.

- I have LXQt 0.14.1 and Lubuntu 20.04 up-to-date.
- I go to Keyboard and Mouse Settings > Mouse and Touchpad > (uncheck) Natural Scrolling
- After reboot it is back to natural scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

For me the setting persistant during reboots. The setting is stored in `~/.config/lxqt/session.conf` in the `[Touchpad]` section. Perhaps you could set it there manually?

For me the entry reads

```
Microsoft%2520Microsoft%25C2%25AE%25202.4GHz%2520Transceiver%2520v9.0%2520Mouse\naturalScrollingEnabled=0
```

You will have to replace the Mouse name of course. I have several other entries there as well.

Comment: I looked in ~/.config/ and I do not have an lxqt subfolder.  Where do I look or how do I create this. Perhaps the difficulty is that this folder and file are not being created so there is no persistence.  Why wouldn't they be created? Should I look for some type of permission restriction?